# SQL column type from Arel::Attributes::Attribute object

Tags: ruby, activerecord, arel, rails-activerecord

**tl;dr** Given an `Arel::Attributes::Attribue` object, say `Model.arel_table[:created_at]` how do get it's SQL type?

**Context:** I'm bypassing the ActiveRecord infrastructure in favour of Arel to write some SQL reports that need to be generated really efficiently. Using Arel's `to_sql` method I'm generating the final SQL and executing it directly via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`. However, I need to apply SQL transformations to certain columns (eg. change timezone of timestamps stored in GMT). Since the number of columns is large (and varying, based on user input), I don't want to hard code these transformations.  I'd like to look at the SQL type of the columns being selected and apply the transformation accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ActiveRecord class set up then you have access to its `columns` and `columns_hash` methods. Those will give you column objects (instances of `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column`) and there you should find `type` and `sql_type` methods. For example:

```
> Model.columns_hash['created_at'].type
 => :datetime 
> Model.columns_hash['created_at'].sql_type
 => "timestamp without time zone"
```

The `sql_type` will be database-specific (that's PostgreSQL above), the `type` will match the type in your migrations so you probably want to use that instead of `sql_type`.

That said, you could probably get away with use the usual ActiveRecord relation methods (which should deal with conversions and time zones for you) and then call `to_sql` at the end:

```
sql = Model.where('created_at > ?', some_time).select('pancakes').to_sql
```

and then feed that SQL into `execute` or `select_rows`. That will let you use most of the usual ActiveRecord stuff while avoiding the overhead of creating a bunch of ActiveRecord wrappers that you don't care about.

Answer (score 1):

Something that might be helpful specifically in arel is [type_cast_for_database](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Table#type_cast_for_database-instance_method). This can be used on an arel table:

```
Model.arel_table.type_cast_for_database(:id, 'test')
=> 0
Model.arel_table.type_cast_for_database(:id, '47test')
=> 47
```

While you don't get the type specifically you can see if values like strings are going to be converted to a number or something.

**EDIT**

It's important to note that this only works if the arel table has a type_caster [able_to_type_cast?](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Table#able_to_type_cast%3F-instance_method). If you get it from the model like above, it should have a type caster.